# Creating and Using jar library

Tags: java, executable-jar

I've created a java file Banana.java directly on C:\ like this :

```
package Bananas;

public class Banana{
   ...
}
```

Then I compile it with this command :

```
javac -d . Banana.java
```

It creates the directory with the class file like this : C:\Bananas\Banana.class
then I put it in a jar file :

```
jar cvf Bananas.jar C:\Bananas\*.class
```

Then I put this jar file at the end of the Classpath of my environment variable like this : ;C:\Bananas.jar

Then I create another java file Test.java that uses this jar file :

```
import Bananas.Banana;

public class Test{
   ...
}
```

and when I compile it via :

```
javac Test.java
```

it gives me the error : package Bananas does not exist.
Does someone see where is my mistake ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it's not finding your class is because you did not create the jar directly.  You included the actual classes in your jar - but not with the directory.  When you're importing `Bananas.Banana`, the compiler is looking for class `Banana` in subdirectory `Bananas` somewhere in your classpath. This class is not found, because your jar contains only `Banana.class` without any subdirectories.  You need to create the jar file with the full subdirectory structure:

```
jar cvf Bananas.jar C:\Bananas
```

This will include directory `Bananas` and all classes inside it.

Comment: I've just tried what you say and the problem is still persisting with the same error. Thanks.

Comment: @user2669068 (1) after you generated the jar file, try typing `jar tvf bananas.jar` - this will list the content of the jar file - make sure that the directory structure is intact; (2) just before compiling you `Test` class, issue `echo %CLASSPATH%` command and check the output - is the jar file included?  If you simply added it to your CLASSPATH env variable, you may need to close the terminal and open it again to recognise the new values of the variable.